# In the use of open source database tools greenDao occur when SQLiteException, experts hope to give

Tags: android, greendao

My code follow:

```
public void saveOrderLists(final AbstractDao<Order, ?> dao,
        final ArrayList<Order> list) {
    if (list == null || list.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    dao.getSession().runInTx(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                Order order = list.get(i);
                dao.insertOrReplaceInTx(order);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

occur follow errors:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-3-thread-2
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Order": syntax error: , while compiling: INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Order ('ID','ORDER_NUMBER','USER_ID','CREATE_TIME','CHECK_IN','CHECK_OUT','TITLE','AMOUNT','ORDER_STATUS') VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:78)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileSql(SQLiteProgram.java:143)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileAndbindAllArgs(SQLiteProgram.java:361)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.acquireAndLock(SQLiteStatement.java:271)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:123)
    at de.greenrobot.dao.AbstractDao.executeInsert(AbstractDao.java:348)
    at de.greenrobot.dao.AbstractDao.insertOrReplace(AbstractDao.java:332)
    at com.yopark.logic.OrderLogic$4.onHttpRsp(OrderLogic.java:396)
    at com.yopark.net.HttpClient.sendReq(HttpClient.java:88)
    at com.yopark.net.NetMgr$1.run(NetMgr.java:43)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: Please formulate your question properly so returning users can benefit from this question as well.

Comment: To me it seems like it is giving you the error because Order is reserved keyword in SQLite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dao.insertOrReplaceInTx(order);
```

the above method takes list as parameter whereas you are passing a single object. Either use insertOrReplace(object) or pass the list that you are getting as parameters.

```
dao.insertOrReplaceInTx(list);
```

Comment: I passed in as a parameter arraylist, in which made a traversal.And I directly call insert () is also wrong

Comment: Why don't you just pass the array list to the method insertOrReplaceInTx(list).

Comment: My database is composed of six tables, other tables corresponding dao calls this method is no problem, can be confusing ah. But thank you for your answer.

Comment: Thank you for your support, I finally found my table name is a keyword database of "Order", the problem lies here, record, and I hope to help a friend behind.